# WebDriver to wait until website is fully loaded

Tags: java, webdriver

I have this code:

```
        String chromeDriverPath = "C:\\buildtools\\chromedriver.exe" ;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get(prerenderUrl);
        //driver.wait(timeout);
        String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
        log(pageSource);
```

If the code `driver.wait(timeout);` is added it throws

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
```

Without the wait the page renders, but the problem is the website that is needed to be rendered is pure Javascript, meaning, it looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="rootPanel">Website will be rendered here</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="app.nocache.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a similar website that rendered with Javascript: http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html

Whereas `app.nocache.js` will trigger the rendering of the whole DOM (at least that is what it does on a normal browser)

If the `driver.wait()` function is not the right one to wait for like 5 to 10 seconds what is the right approach?

Comment: from what  I can see also, the `app.nocache.js` is not even executed in the WebDriver context, on a normal web browser the JS is triggered, thus, the page is rendered correctly.

Comment: The `wait` method in Java comes from the [base `Object` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()), and relates to multithreading. It does not relate to WebDriver and waiting for elements to be available. You’ll want to use `WebDriverWait` or a similar construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do keep an explicit wait condition for the page load. For explicit wait, identify some element from the page and give the WebElement in the condition. Where driver will wait until the item exist.

```
WebDriverWait.until(condition-that-finds-the-element);
```

You can also set an implicit wait as follows by adding the seconds to wait (change 10 in place).

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```